# Excel formula - How to expand data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my brain is melting and I can't figure this out. I have a long list of of rooms of which each type has a code in worksheet 1. These codes are duplicated where room types are similar, so a reception will always be BBA, data capture - BCJ, etc. On the second worksheet I can see what equipment needs to be bought for each room type and each item line has the same codes, BBA, AGA, etc along with quantities needed per room. How can I expand this data on the third spreadsheet showing all rooms with all the equipment needed?

Worksheet 1

```
Room Name    Code
Reception / Workstations    BBA
Data Capture 01    BCJ
Data Capture 02    BCJ
```

Worksheet 2

```
Code    Equip Code    Qty
BBA    BIN021    2
BBA    CHA036    2
BBA    PRI002    1
BBA    TEL001    2
BBA    TRA051    1
BCJ    BIN021    1
BCJ    CHA021    2
BCJ    COM001    1
BCJ    TRO042    2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html#a1) will help you.

Here is the user defined function which you can use and it will grab all the equipment details and put it in one cell (comma separated values).

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)

Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

And then you can use the formula "=myvlookup("BBA",yourRange,2)" and it will return all the equipment for BBA in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to pivot your data (Insert, then Pivot table) on the second sheet.

Set Code as a Row Label, Equip Code as the column label and Quantity as the Value.

You'll have a grid showing each room code with the quantity required for each item.